# Error in phpmyadmin though runs fine in php script

Tags: php, sql, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

Ok so this one is strange and I'm thinking there must be a problem in my sql query but I don't see anything wrong with it. What is happening is that I have a script that I am running in a php script that retrieves all categories that a user has signed up for as well as how many other people have signed up for the same category. When I run the query in the php page it is very slow but does return results. I wanted to see what was happening so I went to phpmyadmin to run the same script and it returns the count of the results very fast but then gives me the following error where the results would normally be displayed:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
       to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT t1.category_id, t3.description AS 'Category',
    t1.list_type_id, t2.name, t1.status_id, t2.user_id,
    t2.email, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( t1.record_date ) AS 'RecordDate',
    (
        SELECT COUNT( category_id ) 
        FROM t1_sub
        WHERE t1_sub = t1.job_ctg_id AND
            t1_sub.list_type_id = t1.list_type_id AND
            t1_sub.status_id =44
    ) AS 'MatchingListings'
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id_rfp_vendor_data = t1.user_id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.type_lookup_id = t1.job_ctg_id
WHERE t1.status_id =43
```

I am at a loss. The reason for my question is really two fold:

1. Is there actually something wrong with my query that I am missing?
2. If not, is the error mysql showing the reason why my script is running slow and that php has some way around this? (Though this seems like an unlikely possibility I just have to ask to be sure)

Thanks!

Comment: Mmmmm... Can you try replacing the quotes `'` by backticks `\``? (Or remove them altogether, alternatively)

Comment: +1: For including the MySQL error # in the tag - Thank you!

Comment: @Pekka let me give that a try and see what happens. @OMG yeah I hate it when someone posts a question and says that they have an error with something and they don't actually give you the error. Like you are some freaking mind reader to guess which error they are having just by looking at the code. I mean I'm sure it's possible but the majority of the time it isn't. Done ranting. :P

Comment: @Pekka no love with the backticks or removing them. Still gives me that same error mentioned above.

Comment: bit of a random one here.. remove the quotes around your alias for AS. FYI the 'as' keyword is optional.

Comment: When it says "Error near ''", that usually means at the end of the statement.  Are you sure you don't have an unclosed quote or `()` somewhere in the statement?  My guess is that you fixed the "bug" when you cleaned the query for posting here (changing table names).  If you still can't get it to work, I'd suggest posting the EXACT query (or showing it to someone if you don't want to publish it)...

Comment: @Paul I did try that per @Pekka suggestion and no go on that.

Comment: @ircmexwell That query is a near perfect replication to what I am using. The only thing I changed was table names and column names. Structure and layout are identical. Is there something missing you see that I missed?

Comment: Ok after the suggestion from @Konerak I looked at removing some of the elements from the query to see what would happen. I started with removing the count subquery as it seemed like the logical offender and it turns out that was where the issue is.

Comment: Ok another find is that if I remove all the labels for the columns then that works.

Comment: Alright now I have run the query just as it is posted and now it is working fine. I am 100% certain that I did not change a thing in the query. I have no answer for what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin takes the liberty to **slightly rewrite your queries** (for example, adds the LIMIT 0,30 clause as to only show the first 30 lines).

Can you enable the query-log and see which query actually gets executed on the server?

If not, try removing elements from the query until it does work. Show us that query. Or show some table definitions?

Comment: in this instance no extra code is being added as I have checked it. Let me see about the query log and see what that shows? After that I will try adding some table definitions.

Comment: I removed the count subquery and it turns out that is the problem. But it seems pretty basic.

Comment: Ok another find is that if I remove all the labels for the columns then that works.

Comment: It works not without changing a thing. I don't know what happened. It must have been a problem within mysql that was temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have spaces in any of your table or column names? If so, enclose them in backticks:

```
`table name`
```

Comment: no spaces. Personally I feel like if you have spaces in your table or column names you should be shot. Again just my opinion though. :P

Comment: @spinon: I agree about the spaces. I'm just not seeing anything weird on line 1 except for the 't1', etc. which I assume are not the real table names.

Comment: Table names aren't keywords are they?

Comment: no table names are not keywords. They are pretty hideous table names and there is no way they could be keywords.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is delete phpmyadmin and promise never to download it again.

Then fire up a command-line mysql prompt, and try the same query. This will tell you whether the query is genuinely bad, or if phpmyadmin was simply trashing it for the perverted pleasure of its misguided authors.

Comment: I do agree somedays. Though phpmyadmin is great for letting me be lazy. Sometimes I don't always want to work with the command line. Great when I want that granular control but not great when I don't want to type a lot. Which on a Friday @ 3 the latter is definitely the case.

Comment: this intrigues me. What don't you like about PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: I have many times read stories where people lose either data or time to phpmyadmin malfunctioning; to me this is just too much of a risk. It may be ok for readonly operations.